# How to darken other datasets when hovering one dataset in chart js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, hover

I have a double doughnut chart. When a mouse hovers a particular dataset, it must maintain its color, while everything else should become darker as shown in this picture [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNmEF.png). In other words, I need the opposite of a hover effect. Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/arrruzhan11/mufw4r07/ (p.s. hover effect in the snippet below is not working).

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var doughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
      datasets: [
        {
        label: 'Fact',
        data: [70, 115, 85, 75, 92, 55, 50, 100, 78, 93, 117, 78],
        backgroundColor: ['#8e1212', '#e72323', '#db31a1', '#a931db', '#5d31db', '#3185db', '#31dbc5', '#31db59', '#c5db31', '#db9931', '#e8511c', '#ff7b7b'],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ['#693737', '#ac5e5e', '#a86491', '#9464a8', '#7664a8', '#6486a8','#64a89f', '#64a874', '#9fa864', '#a88e64', '#ab6e59', '#d7a3a3'],
        hoverOffset: 10,
        },
        {
        label: 'Plan',
        data: [66, 67, 107, 65, 67, 64, 64, 65, 128, 82, 85, 90],
        backgroundColor: ['#8e1212', '#e72323', '#db31a1', '#a931db', '#5d31db', '#3185db','#31dbc5', '#31db59', '#c5db31', '#db9931', '#e8511c', '#ff7b7b'],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ['#693737', '#ac5e5e', '#a86491', '#9464a8', '#7664a8', '#6486a8', '#64a89f', '#64a874', '#9fa864', '#a88e64', '#ab6e59', '#d7a3a3'],
        hoverOffset: 10,}
        ]},
        options: {
            tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                beforeBody: function (chart, data) {
                const hoverval = document.getElementById('hoverval');
                var datasetIndex = chart[0].datasetIndex;
                var label = data.datasets[datasetIndex].label;
                hoverval.innerText = `${label}`;
                                }
                },
            },
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
                position: "left",
              align: "start",
              fullSize: true,
              },
            hover: {
                mode: 'dataset',
            },
        }})
```

```css
#hoverval {
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<h3>
How to darken other datasets when hovering one dataset in chart js?
</h3>
<div id="hoverval"> </div>
<canvas id="myChart" width="470" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/legend/events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an `onHover` function as follows:

```
onHover: (e, activeElements, chart) => {
  const datasets = chart.config.data.datasets;
  if (activeElements[0]) {
    let ctx = activeElements[0].element.$context;
    datasets[ctx.datasetIndex ? 0 : 1].backgroundColor = hoverBgColor;
    datasets[ctx.datasetIndex ? 1 : 0].backgroundColor = bgColor;
  } else {
    datasets.forEach(ds => ds.backgroundColor = bgColor);
  }
  chart.update();
}
```

> For further information, please consult the Chart.js documentation [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#events).

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works. Note that this sample uses Chart.js v3.8.2, the current most recent version of the library.

```js
const bgColor = ['#8e1212', '#e72323', '#db31a1', '#a931db', '#5d31db', '#3185db', '#31dbc5', '#31db59', '#c5db31', '#db9931', '#e8511c', '#ff7b7b'];
const hoverBgColor = ['#693737', '#ac5e5e', '#a86491', '#9464a8', '#7664a8', '#6486a8', '#64a89f', '#64a874', '#9fa864', '#a88e64', '#ab6e59', '#d7a3a3'];

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Fact',
        data: [70, 115, 85, 75, 92, 55, 50, 100, 78, 93, 117, 78],
        backgroundColor: bgColor
      },
      {
        label: 'Plan',
        data: [66, 67, 107, 65, 67, 64, 64, 65, 128, 82, 85, 90],
        backgroundColor: bgColor
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    onHover: (e, activeElements, chart) => {
      const datasets = chart.config.data.datasets;
      if (activeElements[0]) {
        let ctx = activeElements[0].element.$context;
        datasets[ctx.datasetIndex ? 0 : 1].backgroundColor = hoverBgColor;
        datasets[ctx.datasetIndex ? 1 : 0].backgroundColor = bgColor;
      } else {
        datasets.forEach(ds => ds.backgroundColor = bgColor);
      }
      chart.update();
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: "left",
        align: "start",
        fullSize: true,
      }
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'dataset',
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.8.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<div id="hoverval"> </div>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```